# Terminal can't execute files In CWD

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, catalina, bash

I stated having this behaviour recently when I tried executing my `sh` script via `sh my_script.sh`.

It was a simple script with some pyinstaller command.
Now, the issue that I'm having is that my terminal is not able to access/read file in present directory.

If I give `ls`, I can see the file in the directory, but when I try to run that file, my terminal just shows
`zsh: command not found: hulusubs_dl_osx`

Binary file that I'm trying to run is `hulusubs_dl_osx`.

```
xonshiz@MacBook-Pro Downloads % ls
Bills           
Notes
Some Important Things
hulusubs_dl_osx
xonshiz@MacBook-Pro Downloads % hulusubs_dl_osx
zsh: command not found: hulusubs_dl_osx
xonshiz@MacBook-Pro Downloads %
```

As you can see that the file `hulusubs_dl_osx` shows up, but when I try to access it, I get command not found error.

But, if I were to provide full path to that file, then terminal is able to run that file

```
xonshiz@MacBook-Pro Downloads % ls                                       
Bills           
Notes
Some Important Things
hulusubs_dl_osx
xonshiz@MacBook-Pro Downloads % hulusubs_dl_osx                          
zsh: command not found: hulusubs_dl_osx
xonshiz@MacBook-Pro Downloads % /Users/xonshiz/Downloads/hulusubs_dl_osx --version
2021.01.08.3
xonshiz@MacBook-Pro Downloads %
```

I can access my other installations like Python, brew etc., just fine. But, I can't access any file. It's not just the case with this `hulusubs_dl` file, but with any given file. I was able to run the file directly few days ago.

Does anyone have any clue what might be happening? What I might've changed that caused this?

P.S: I'm on Catalina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no path is given (either an absolute or a relative one) the shell searches through the directories listed in `$PATH` to find commands to execute. If the current directory isn't included there, you need to use a relative path like

```
./hulusubs_dl_osx
```

In theory you could solve this by adding `.` to `PATH` but this is considered bad practice due to the potential security risk (imagine somebody putting a fake `ls` command in one of your directories).

Comment: Ah, thanks. That worked and thanks for the explanation about the `.`. However, the weird thing is that I could call any file directly without prepending `./` earlier. I'm just wondering what could've caused this issue. Well, I've accepted your solution, as it works and explanation is there. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Xonshiz Could you run files in the CWD directly, or via another command like `sh my_script.sh`? (Note: in this case the directories in `$PATH` are searched for "sh", and then *it* looks in the CWD for "my_script.sh")

Comment: Yep, I was directly able to call `sh my_script.sh` and it was working. Like I said, I ran that command and after that this issue started happening. I just checked, I can run this `sh` command just fine, without prepending `./` to it. But, I can't run any other file/binary without `./`.

Comment: @Xonshiz And these files you are trying to run are all in the same directory?

Comment: Nope, different directories. But, I do move in the directory via terminal. Even when I give `ls`, it's showing the files (which I mentioned in my original question). So, that means terminal is indeed able to access these files. But, I'm not sure why it isn't able to call them directly.

Comment: @Xonshiz Most probably some of these directories are in your `PATH`, some are not. `ls` just lists any directory content, it doesn't care about execution.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320632/why-do-i-need-to-type-before-executing-a-program-in-the-current-directory and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix have some more details on this

Comment: Ohhhh damn. Thanks a lot @nohillside for these links. Going through these, it all makes sense. I always thought if terminal can see files via `ls`, it should be able to call them from there itself. Good learn that this is not how it works, lol. Thanks again! :)